# unable to convert <img/> tag to <amp-img> successfully

Tags: php, yii2, amp-html

Here is my code using HTML string inside amp page:

```
<?php
use DomDocument;
use Lullabot\AMP\AMP;
use Lullabot\AMP\Validate\Scope;
use common\helpers\StringHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
$amp = new AMP();

<body>
    $html = $model->content;
    $amp->loadHtml($html);
    $amp_html = $amp->convertToAmpHtml();
    if(isset($model['image'])){ ?>
        <section class= "image-banner">
            <amp-img src="<?= Url::to('@web/uploads/'.$model->image); ?>"
            layout="responsive" width="900" height="467"></amp-img>
        </section>
    <?php } ?>

<section class="content-section">
    <h1><?= $model->title;?></h1>
    <?= $amp_html ?>
    <div>
        <?php if(Yii::$app->controller->id == "careers"){?>
            <a href= "<?=Url::to(['/careers/'.$model->slug]) ?> ">
                Fill application form.
            </a>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Result after inspect in browser:

```
<a class="align-left" href="https://freelancercompany.com.np/admin/index.php?r=media%2Fview&amp;slug=dg2">
    <amp-img class="media-image media-9 align-left i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined" src="https://freelancercompany.com.np/uploads/2017/06/dg2.png" alt="dg2" width="1300" data-id="9" height="431" layout="responsive">
    <i-amphtml-sizer style="display: block; padding-top: 33.1538%;"></i-amphtml-sizer></amp-img> 
</a>
```

Here the problem is I am unable to get the image it comes blank in place. As you can see image source clearly on amp-image tag.